# Why this error - "TypeError: ... is not a constructor"

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'd wish to created a namespace "SK3". I'd wish also to create a constructor "SK3.lib.f.Strext" that adds certain functionality via prototype. The SK3.lib.f.Strext code is not inlined but attached from a separate file.

Is this approach below not valid? 
I get "TypeError: SK3.lib.f.Strext is not a constructor"

```js
if (typeof SK3 == "undefined") {
            SK3 = {};
            SK3.v = {};//variables
            SK3.e = {};//events
            SK3.f = {};//functions
            SK3.lib = {};
            SK3.lib.v = {};
            SK3.lib.e = {};
            SK3.lib.f = {};
        }

SK3.lib.f.Strext = (function () {
    var me = SK3.lib.f.Strext;
    var buffer = me.buffer = [];
    me.prototype.append = function (a) {
        buffer.push(a);
        return true
    };
    me.prototype.trim = function () {
        buffer.replace(/^\s+|\s{2,}|\s+$/g, "");
        buffer.replace(/[\r\n]+/g, "");
        return true
    };
    me.prototype.stripSlash = function () {
        buffer.replace(/\\+/g, "");
        return true
    };
    me.prototype.toString = function () {
        return buffer.join("");
    };
    return me;
})();

var thumbs = new SK3.lib.f.Strext();
```

Comment: It's really hard to answer because the code you posted does not make sense, and the way in which it does not make sense is very confusing.

Comment: In fact the code you posted wouldn't get to the `var thumbs` line, because the variable "me" in that function is `undefined` so any attempt to access its "prototype" property immediately fail.

Answer (score 1):

With how you have it written, SK3.lib.f.Strext is not a constructor. It's a self executing method. Try removing the () around the entire function, and the closing set of ()'s in this constructor that executes the method.

Comment: It's actually *not* a self-executing method; it's the value *returned* from that function call, which is, as far as I can tell, `undefined`.

Comment: So (function() { }) () is not a self executing method?

Comment: Yes, *that* is, but `SK3.lib.f.Strext` is assigned the return value from that function call. Inside that bizarre code, the variable `me` is set to that weird property, which will be `undefined` at the point that happens. It's more-or-less inscrutable what's supposed to happen here.

Comment: Right, right, excuse my poor explanation. What I mean to say is that this doesn't need to be a self executing function at all. However, that's just the tip of it. The prototype methods should be outside of the constructor function as well, among other issues.